# Issues with outputs for dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic

I'm working with a template class for dynamic arrays, and my code has compiled successfully, however my get function for a given element in the dynamic array does not seem to be working. Nothing seems to be outputted whenever I output the function, but this doesn't make sense, because my size function works fine, and shows that there is indeed something within the array, I just can't output it. Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Wrapper{
private:
    T* array;
    int size;
public:
    Wrapper(){
        array = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }
    int returnSize(){
        return size;
    }
    void addEntry(string input){
        if(returnSize()==0){
            array = new string[returnSize()+1];
            array[returnSize()] = input;
            size+=1;
        }
        else{
            T* newArray = new T[returnSize()+1];
            for(int i = 0; i<returnSize(); i++){
                newArray[i] = array[i];
            }
            newArray[returnSize()] = input;
            size+=1;
            string *array = new string[returnSize()];
            array = newArray;
        }
        
    }

    bool deleteEntry(string input){
        int mySize = returnSize();
        string* testArray = new string[mySize];
        for(int i = 0; i<mySize; i++){
            if(array[i]==input){
                return true;
                break;
            }
        }
        string*newArray = new string[mySize-1];
        for(int i = 0; i<mySize; i++){
            if(array[i]!=input){
                newArray[i+=1] = array[i];
        }
        }
        delete[]array;
        array = newArray;
        return true;
        
    }
    string getEntry(int input){
        if(input>size){
            return NULL;
        }
        return this->array[input];
    }
    void operator=(const Wrapper w){
        this->size = w.returnSize();
        string *newArray = new string[size];
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
            newArray[i] = w.getEntry(i);
        }
        this->array = newArray;
    }
    ~Wrapper(){
        delete[] array;
    }

};

int main(){
    Wrapper<string> w;
    w.addEntry("sam");
    w.addEntry("Josh");
    w.addEntry("tom");
    cout<<"Here"<<endl;
    cout<<w.returnSize();
    for(int i = 0; i<<w.returnSize(); i++){
        cout<<w.getEntry(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should output a newline at the end. The shell prompt might just overwrite your output.

Comment: *and my code has compiled successfully, however ...*  -- Secret words for "I didn't debug my program".  Compiling successfully only means there are no syntax errors.  It has nothing to do with whether your program has no logical bugs.

Comment: Just a style note, but using `returnSize()` everywhere internally just makes the code harder to read. Use `size` directly. You should also make the `returnSize` function `const`.

Comment: In `addEntry` the `string *array = new string[returnSize()];` shadows the member variable. That whole line seems to just need to go.

Comment: `int main() { Wrapper<string> w; w.addEntry("x"); Wrapper<string> w2 = w; }`  This will create a double-delete error.  Looks like you need to read up on the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: Did you run this in a debugger?  I get a segmentation fault , because the name shadowing means you never update the `array` member.  After removing the offending line, it works fine.  Well, almost fine; you have `i << w.returnSize()` in the final `for` where you meant `i < w.returnSize()`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How so? I think operator= causes a memory leak instead because it doesn't delete the old array of this. `addEntry` also leaks the old array. And `deleteEntry` leaks the testArray and is totaly non-functional.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow -- `Wrapper<string> w2 = w;` -- The function that's called is the copy constructor, not assignment operator.  And to that, the `operator=` is messed up anyway, before the first line of `operator=` is executed.  This is because `Wrapper` is passed by value, thus invoking the copy constructor.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I guess I know why g++ says: *warning: implicitly-declared ‘constexpr Wrapper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::Wrapper(const Wrapper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy] note: because ‘Wrapper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ has user-provided ‘void Wrapper<T>::operator=(Wrapper<T>) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to collect the findings, if you delete this line from `addEntry`:

```
           string *array = new string[returnSize()];
```

and change your final for loop to:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < w.returnSize(); i++){
        cout<<w.getEntry(i)<<"\n";
    }
```

then this does exactly what you expect.  I've run it myself.